# ServiceBase class in .NET 6 Windows Service Application

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, .net-6.0

In a .NET 6 Windows service application, we have a reference to the class 'System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase' from 'System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.dll'. However, when we decompile the code, we notice that the methods appear to be throwing unsupported exceptions, as shown in the sample code below:

```
public ServiceBase() { throw new System.PlatformNotSupportedException(System.SR.PlatformNotSupported_ServiceController); }
protected virtual void OnStart(string[] args) { throw new System.PlatformNotSupportedException(System.SR.PlatformNotSupported_ServiceController); }
protected virtual void OnStop() { throw new System.PlatformNotSupportedException(System.SR.PlatformNotSupported_ServiceController); }
```

Interestingly, we do not encounter any exceptions at runtime, even though we are instantiating the ServiceBase class. Furthermore, when we checked the GitHub repository for .NET runtime, the source code for ServiceBase does not show 'Unsupported'. You can find the source code here: GitHub Repository Link: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v7.0.1/src/libraries/System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController/src/System/ServiceProcess/ServiceBase.cs

Our question is: Is the ServiceBase class truly unsupported in .NET 6 on Windows platform? If it is unsupported, why are there no exceptions thrown at runtime when using it?

We would greatly appreciate any insights or clarification regarding this matter. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: "However, when we decompile the code" How? You just clicked on it in Visual Studio and let it do its magic? VS will just choose the wrong version from the nuget package then. The correct one will be used when debugging or deploying (if not configured wrong). You might want to use a decompiling tool and directly open the version of the assembly in the runtimes folder of the nuget package for your target to see the "real" stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Ralf.
Yes, I also tried to decompile using dotpeek and there also it's marked as unsupported

Comment: Did that also and looked into the nugets folder "\runtimes\win\lib\net6.0" and the assembly there looks good.

Comment: You need to look in the "runtimes" folder as i showed you to get whats used at runtime. "lib" might be incomplete or something for the wrong plattform. Its used and loaded by Visual Studio to compile your stuff against so rather only used by code completion or similar functionality. Things that more or less only need surfaces and not implementations.

Comment: Thanks @Ralf. When I decompiled the assembly inside 'runtimes' folder, everything looks good.